# Installation .deb file without superuser privilege

Tags: 16.04, package-management, permissions, dpkg, sudo

Sorry I'm quite new to this OS, and I tried to install some software on school linux machine.

After I downloaded the .deb file, and tried to do `sudo dpkg -i pageckName.db`, it returns `MyUsername is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.`

So I tried the `dpkg -i pageckName.db`, it returns `dpkg:error: requested operation requires superuser privilege`.

Also, the `dpkg -i pageckName.db --force-not-root --root=$HOME` fails me on the same reason...Any ideas?

// Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Thank you so much!

Comment: You do not have administrative privileges in a school computer, as usual, and **as it should be**.  It's exactly the same in Windows (if not, it should be). Please contact you IT department and request the installation of said software.

Comment: I managed to install sublime text last time, it's doable =.=

Comment: It wouldn't be if it was properly set up. The point being you're attempting to do something you shouldn't and, obviously, we're NOT going to help you with that. The consequences for you can range from a mild admonition to expulsion. In a work environment that's cause for termination in each and every western country and many others. Anything else you need help with?

Comment: I think this question should be asked, and I think there should be a correct answer (like the first comment by CelticWarrior, but I think the second comment is an over-reaction).

Comment: @sudodus That kind of "over-reactions" are part of my daily job at HR. I'm the one that has to do that exact same speech at least twice a week. It gets worse with any fresh batch of interns. One would think they should be used to it by now since school but this question is a textbook example of why that's not the case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "install". It is possible to extract the file contents of a .deb file using dpkg-deb -x , but whether you can actually use the software after extracting it locally depends on how it is written.

A lot of Linux software will be expecting to find its resource files in standard locations specified at compile-time, such as /usr/sAhare or /usr/lib, which will fail if the software is not installed in the usual location.

Also any system-wide configuration files installed by the package, such as .desktop files that create entries in the start menu, will not function as intended if installed in the wrong location.

Another solution is to chroot yourself in your home directory as explained here : https://serverfault.com/questions/23734/is-there-any-way-to-get-apt-to-install-packages-to-my-home-directory

For simple applications those two methods can work

Comment: I actually did not use any of these command to install it by the end. I found the https://download.sublimetext.com/sublime_text_3_build_3126_x64.tar.bz2 and https://github.com/atom/atom/releases ; and then used the tar command http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file

Comment: Yes but your question was about a generic .deb package which can be muh richer than a sublime or atom release.

Next time, please tell in your initial question what package you are trying to install so peaople can give you a taillored solution.

For the generic question "how can I install any .deb package ?" , the solution is much more complex than for the question "How can I install this specific app without admin privilege ?"